# Shredded Coconut as a Substitute for...?

Tags: substitutions, coconut

I had a recipe that called for unsweetened shredded coconut and the only package I could find brought a TON of it. I ended up not caring for the recipe so now I have all this extra shredded coconut. Since it is unsweetened, it isn't what most dessert recipes call for. What, if anything, can I use this product as a substitute for? I have tried using it in place of bread crumbs but other ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: This is a super old question and there has already been an accepted answer, but a lot of south Indian dishes use shredded coconut, maybe you could look into that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My wife loves it toasted.  Toast shredded coconut in a dry pan or oven and put on ice cream and other deserts.  It's really tasty.  Like toasting other nuts be careful as if you blink it may burn.

Comment: TOASTED COCONUT CREAM PIE! I *hate* shredded coconut, but toasted... and in pie... it ain't so bad. I toast it in a bit of butter and then just finish making the cream filling in the same pan.

Answer (score 2):

I adore using it as breadcrumbs (as you said), particularly on shrimp, then pan- or deep-fried.

You can also use it as a textural component in bread.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a substitution, but if you're a fan of coconut, you can make coconut ice cream, or coconut sorbet for those who can't do dairy.